# Backbone Namespace convention best practice

Tags: backbone.js, namespaces

This is a single question, but I have all my head about the fact if this is a good practice or not.

Basically, let's say we have this trivial scenario:

```
 (function(){

   window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
   };

   App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});
   App.Views.PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({});
   App.Collections.PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});


   var person = new App.Person(); 

 })();
```

So... if we are working on a small application, maybe it is ok, but when working on large size applications, it is ok to grab all the application into a self invoking anonimous function?, or what other practices do u guys point me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided to use RequireJS to organize our huge codebase. It turned out great.

It encourages modular and clean structure. We ended up without having a single `window.Whatever` globally visible stateful troublemaker, and we like it.

If you're new to Backbone/RequireJS I recommend you the following tutorial:

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Comment: @andresmijares25 You don't want to be attaching much to the global app object, an object which should only exist in debug/dev mode btw (on prod it is required in, you always reference the required app object (via requirejs) it is just for debugging in browser). All you really need on it is a 'state' model. Rest with RequireJS - route to modules and create views/models/collects - when going to a new route most of these would get freed for garbage collection. It's also a good idea to have a view-subview system to ensure your DOM is cleaned up properly (remove a view and it removes subviews too)

Answer (score 2):

If you're building out a Backbone app of any non-trivial size, go with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). I'd recommend their [Sugar Notation](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar).  The benefits to this approach:

- Less risk of dependency issues. If the script is not defined, you won't be able to use it. With global objects you'll occasionally forget to define a script, but you won't notice it since a previous script already loaded it up. Then 1 out of every 25 times your page will fail because the calling order gets jumbled.  This the worst error imaginable, and you can completely avoid it.
- No need to pollute the global scope with your instance variables
- Cleaner to require's ideals

What this means is you save the namespacing for your directory structure.  How you define the variables representing the classes is more of a "gentleman's agreement".